# Ensure file insertion finished with GridFS - MongoDB Java API

Tags: java, mongodb, save, gridfs

I have a REST service to upload images and this is the main code in charge of the registration in mongodb:

```
public String writeFiles(InputStream inputStream, String fileName, String contentType) throws IOException {
    // save the file
    GridFS gridFS = new GridFS(getDB(), Collections.PICTURES_FILES.name());

    GridFSInputFile gridFSInputFile = gridFS.createFile(inputStream, fileName);
    gridFSInputFile.setContentType(contentType);
    gridFSInputFile.setMetaData(new BasicDBObject(ORIGINAL_PICT_COL, true));

    gridFSInputFile.save();
    return gridFSInputFile.getId();
}
```

The service then return the file ID to the client so that this one can ask for and display the uploaded image.

The problem is for very large images: sometime while requesting an image by its ID right after the upload gives a HTTP 404 error (due to unknown image ID on server side, this is a correct behavior).
I suppose it happens because registration time on the server side is greater than time used to get the ID back and request the new image on the client side - i.e the '.save()' operation is async, right ?

My question: How to be sure that the save operation has been completed before returning the ID in the given code ?
Or how to obtain a result object as for .insert operation ?

Does a

```
    gridFSInputFile.validate();
```

would be enought ?

Or

```
  getDB().getLastError()
```

?

I cannot reproduce easily this "bug" so i ask the question in case someone with experience already know how to solve this. Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using a recent version of the Java driver (2.10 or later), try creating an instance of MongoClient instead of an instance of Mongo.  The default write concern is WriteConcern.ACKNOWLEDGED for instances of MongoClient, so the save method will not complete until the write operation has completed.

Otherwise, in your getDB method (not shown), call the method DB.setWriteConcern(WriteConcern.SAFE) to change the default write concern.

The other possibility is that you are reading from a secondary member of your replica set.  The default is to read from the primary, but if you are overriding that, then your reads will be eventually consistent, and you could see this problem in that case as well.

Comment: Hello. Thanks for your helpful answer :) I've decided to set the WriteConcern to ACKNOWLEDGE on my getDB for the moment as a quick fix and i may refactor later with MongoClient. Thanks again